# Discrepancy between date-fns startOfWeek and format W

Tags: javascript, date, date-fns

I'm having a problem with `date-fns` and the way it handles "start of weeks".

The "start of week" of 2015-01-01, according to my calendar, was 2014-12-29.

But, `date-fns#startOfWeek` tells me otherwise:

```
❯❯❯ dateFns.startOfWeek(new Date('2015-01-01'))
Sun Dec 28 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
```

If I format the result of `startOfWeek` (2014-12-28) to just return the week number, what I get is "52" (which doesn't match with the result provided by `dateFns#startOfWeek`):

```
❯❯❯ dateFns.format(new Date('2014-12-28'), 'W')
"52"
```

But, if I format the original date (2015-01-01), it will return "1":

```
❯❯❯ dateFns.format(new Date('2015-01-01'), 'W')
"1"
```

Why is there this discrepancy? What's the proper way to get the right "start of week" date and week number?

Note, I'm setting `TZ=Etc/UTC` in my environment variables when I run the above commands on my Node.js CLI. So it shouldn't be a timezone issue.

Comment: I personally find `moment.js` more developer friendly

Comment: @carkod I'm migrating from Moment.js to date-fns, I need to reduce the size of the bundle.

Comment: The first day of the week is an administrative thing. In some places it's Sunday, others it's Monday, in some it's Saturday. There may be others.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What you are getting is correct. By default, a week starts on Sunday. But if you want to start it from Monday, you can do it like this:

`var result = startOfWeek(new Date(2014, 8, 2, 11, 55, 0), {weekStartsOn: 1})`

[Reference](https://date-fns.org/v1.30.1/docs/startOfWeek)

Example:

```js
var result = dateFns.startOfWeek(new Date('2015-01-01'))
console.log(result);

result = dateFns.startOfWeek(new Date('2015-01-01'), {weekStartsOn: 1})
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/1.30.1/date_fns.min.js"></script>
```

Concerning the week numbers, `W` in [format()](https://date-fns.org/v1.30.1/docs/format) gives you ISO week number, meaning it starts form Monday. Moreover there were only 52 weeks in 2014.

Source: https://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2014

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this doesn't explain the discrepancy between `startOfWeek` and `format(x, 'W')` tho, may you help me on this?

Comment: Even that is correct. `W` in format() gives you ISO week number, meaning it starts form Monday. Moreover there were only 52 weeks in 2014. Source: https://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2014

Comment: Oh I see, thanks, that's confusing  may you update your answer to include this information please?

Comment: Sure. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 8):

I don't know when it was added but you can also use `startOfISOWeek` instead of `startOfWeek` for `date-fns` in 2021.

`startOfISOWeek` returns the date of `Monday` instead of `Sunday` as start of the week.